# Why alert is not showing up in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using `.alert` in swiftUI but its not showing up. below is my code --

```
 Button(action: {
                            // Dismiss the PopUp
                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
                                print("On Submit clicked-------------->")
                                hideKeyboard()
                                
                                if self.textFieldValidatorEmail(self.emailTxtField) {
                                    self.isEmailValid = true
                                } else {
                                    self.isEmailValid = false
                                   // self.emailTxtField = ""
                                }
                                
                                if !isEmailValid {
                                    //return
                                 
                                } else {
                                    LoginViewModel.params = ["user": nameTxtField.text, "email":emailTxtField.text]
                                            self.viewModel.send(event: .onAppear)
                                }
                             
                                    
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Submit")
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                .background(Color.yellow)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 19, weight: .semibold))
                            
                        })
                        .alert(isPresented: $isEmailValid,
                               content: {
                                Alert(title: Text("Message"),
                                      message: Text("downloadModel.alertMsg"),
                                      dismissButton: .destructive(Text("Ok"),
                                                                  action: {
                                                                    withAnimation{
                                                                        
                                                                    }
                                                                  }))
                               })
```

Comment: Is the line `self.isEmailValid = true` definitely getting called?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure because I can't see your properties or full code if you can share with me your project through GitHub so I can take a more precise look, but as if now I believe you have to toggle the alert like to let the pop up know that you are triggering it or there must be some sort of .onAppear or onTapGesture condition, to make it equal to be the true value.

Long story short try to add a showing an alert condition and toggle the alert property somewhere in the action of your code.

Because I believe you did everything correctly my friend but the only thing you have to trigger is your alert somehow.